# How to generate and validate token manually in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, cookies, token

I have a laravel API backend for my SPA frontend.
The client gets a bearer token on login and a refresh token in a httpOnly cookie.
The refresh token is for remember me functionality.
As a silent login, I want to check this refresh token and refresh the bearer token so the user doesn't have to login again.

for the Bearer token I use https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/.
But I can't figure out how to make a refresh token and validate it.

my AuthController looks like this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        /**
         * request remember-me: <true>
         * create cookie
         * send back
         *
         * need new function that checks silent login
         */

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }
        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        //The only way I found to make a token for the cookie
        $refresh = auth()->attempt($validator->validated());

        $cookie = cookie('__refresh-token')
            ->withValue($refresh)
            ->withExpires(strtotime("+6 months"))
            ->withSecure(true)
            ->withHttpOnly(true)
            ->withSameSite("none");

        return $this->createNewToken($token)->cookie($cookie);
    }
    /**
     * Register a User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
        }
        $user = User::create(array_merge(
            $validator->validated(),
            ['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
        ));

        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User successfully registered',
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        //TODO: invalidate access-token in cookie

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User successfully signed out']);
    }
    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->createNewToken(auth()->refresh());
    }
    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function userProfile()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }
    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function createNewToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/#create-the-authcontroller also `tymon/jwt-auth` is pretty dead with regards to development/fixes